# How to change the degrees of freedom in a chi-square test

Tags: r, statistics, p-value

I'm trying to calculate the P-value with the goodness of fit test for the Poisson Distribution

The observed datapoints are :118 64 18 and the expected are: 120 61.25 18.8

I calculated the probability with the Poisson distribution so the df value would be 3-1-1=1

I got from R that the df=4

This is what I put into R:

```
Chi.Observed <- c(118,64,18)
Chi.Expected <- c(120,61.2,18.8)
chisq.test(Chi.Observed, Chi.Expected)
```

and the answer was:

```
        Pearson's Chi-squared test
Chi.Observed and Chi.Expected
X-squared = 6, df = 4, p-value = 0.1991
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not df=6-2 or 4?

Comment: Yeah , because there are three categories and I already estimated the mean from the data so that makes a df of 1

Comment: the answer is a p=0.66, I didn't see that there were only 2 categories tho. Still don't really know how they did that.

Comment: by "Poissont" do you mean "truncated Poisson", or is this a typo for "Poisson"?

Comment: Typo for Poisson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about this problem and reading Ben's answer above, I believe I have an explanation and/or answer.  This problem is two-fold, using the correct form of the Chisq test and getting the degree of freedoms correct.

The first problem in the using the correct form of the chisq.test.  If you use the form: `chisq.test(x, y)` this results in the creation of a 3x3 contingency table and results in a p-value which is too low.
See test1 below. `test1$observed` and `test1$expected` are not returning the correct input.

The correct format for is `chisq.test(x, p) #where p is the expected probability of x.`
This is shown as test2 below.  Now the p-value has changed from 19% to 90%. (This would be my answer, but I will defer to a better statistician.)

To adjust the degrees of freedom to 1, see Ben Bolker's answer.  Now results are shown as test3, with the p-value 66%

Hope this provides an acceptable explanation.

```
Chi.Observed <- c(118,64,18)
Chi.Expected <- c(120,61.2,18.8)

test1<-chisq.test(Chi.Observed, Chi.Expected) # this is 3x3 contgency table.
test1
# Pearson's Chi-squared test
# 
# data:  Chi.Observed and Chi.Expected
# X-squared = 6, df = 4, p-value = 0.1991
# 
#This result is incorrect as it...
# forms a 3x3 contingency table as shown by: 
test1$observed   # observed counts 
test1$expected   # expected counts under the null


#chisq using the expected probabilities:
test2<-chisq.test(Chi.Observed, p= Chi.Expected/sum(Chi.Expected))
test2
# Chi-squared test for given probabilities
# 
# data:  Chi.Observed
# X-squared = 0.19548, df = 2, p-value = 0.9069


#adjust degrees of freedon as per Ben's answer
test3 <- chisq.test(Chi.Observed,  p = Chi.Expected/sum(Chi.Expected))
test3$parameter <- c(df=1)
test3$p.value <- pchisq(test3$statistic, df=test3$parameter, lower.tail=FALSE)
test3 
# Chi-squared test for given probabilities
# 
# data:  Chi.Observed
# X-squared = 0.19548, df = 1, p-value = 0.6584
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll show how to change the test in a minute, but there are a few issues here. (Except for the df adjustment, [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92627/how-to-use-the-chi-squared-test-to-determine-if-data-follow-the-poisson-distribu) covers exactly the same ground as this answer, and a bit more ...)

- it would help to have a little more info about how you derived the expected counts. Reconstructing:

  - `dpois(0:1,lambda=0.51)*200` gives `(120.09912,61.25055)` and `ppois(1,lambda=0.51,lower.tail=FALSE)` gives 18.6, so I'm assuming that what you have here are the probabilities of 0, 1, and >= 2 counts from 200 counts
  - `sum(Chi.Observed)` is 200  and `sum((0:2)*Chi.Observed/sum(Chi.Observed))` is 0.5, so that agrees pretty well.

  So you have derived 2 pieces of information from 3 numeric values to generate your expected values, and it does seem reasonable that your df should be 1.
- specifying `x` and `y` **does not do what you think (or I thought) it does**: as @Dave2e points out, what you really want is to specify `p` instead.

  > if ‘x’ is a vector
  >    and ‘y’ is not given, then a *goodness-of-fit test* is performed ... the
  >    hypothesis tested is whether the population probabilities equal
  >    those in ‘p’, or are all equal if ‘p’ is not given.

  Here's how to hack your test:

```
Chi.Observed <- c(118,64,18)
Chi.Expected <- c(120,61.2,18.8)
cc <- chisq.test(Chi.Observed, 
         p = Chi.Expected/sum(Chi.Expected))
cc$parameter <- c(df=1)
cc$p.value <- pchisq(cc$statistic,df=cc$parameter,
      lower.tail=FALSE)
cc 
## Pearson's Chi-squared test    
## data:  Chi.Observed and Chi.Expected
## X-squared = 0.19548, df = 1, p-value = 0.6584
```

---

Looking at the code for what *actually* happens when `x` and `y` are both given as vectors: R constructs this table

```
table(factor(Chi.Expected), factor(Chi.Observed))

       18 64 118
  18.8  1  0   0
  61.2  0  1   0
  120   0  0   1
```

and then does the contingency table analysis (i.e., testing the null hypothesis of row/column independence) on it!  This one of the best R traps I've seen in a long time ...

Comment: The question is: are the numbers independently generated.                                             
I derived them from a table where the frequency of 0's are 118; 1's are 64 and >1's are 18. Then used the poisson formula the calculate the independence.  The H0 is that the individuals have a poisson distribution and the Ha is that they haven't. So I need to use the X^2 goodness-of-fit to calculate for that.

Comment: @BenBolker, Can you elaborate on your solution some more? A p value of 1.4% seems too low considering the first bin is has 118 out of 120 expected. A gut feeling is the H0 is feasible.  
If you use this `cc<-chisq.test(Chi.Observed, p= Chi.Expected/sum(Chi.Expected))` and then change the df to 1, this results in a p value closer to 0.66

Comment: Reading the doc more carefully, I think you're right: specifying `x` and `y` doesn't do what I expected.